# How can I have the so-called 'shape key' AND the vertex color to change synchronously in this Geometry Nodes situation

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

I have this but I can't make the vertex color that affects the material to change like:

- Ball = Green
- Cube = Pink

How can it be done?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is capture the positions of the points where you instantiate your objects with `Capture Attribute`.

From these positions you can easily calculate the factor for the *RGB/XZY* crossfade in dependence on the `Scene Time`.

On the one hand you use this factor directly when blending the two shapes, and on the other hand you use it directly as a factor for blending the two colors.

[image]

That's how I would have solved it:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer from a friend, excellent!

Preview nodes but it's better to check out the .blend.

NOTE, the **'Domain Size'** uses **'Face Count'** output in the **'Color'** frame, **not 'Point Count'** - I heard this is because vertex colors are actually 'Face Corner' data, not Vertex data. UVs are Face Corner data as well, fyi. That's what I heard.

[image]

[image]