# Create parametrical matrix

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to create some sort of parametrical shape matrix. The goal is to have a grid of lets say cubes. Based on their position in the grid they are morphed to a cylinder, for the y direction and scaled along the z Axis in the y direction. Everything shell be created in geo nodes.

The matrix is for a visualisation of the various sursteps in the Morphing process.

Can someone Help me pleased with a node Setup?

I have provided my current setup and the result.

[image: Node Setup]
[image: Result]

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264077

Comment: Hello there, thank you for the suggestion.
Off to a good start. I will try to work from there.

Comment: Unfotunetly i am only able to achieve some sort of pattern but not quite what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I ended up with this.

[image: Node Setup]

The idea is that you have a shape, in my case a grid, which defines the positions of the objects in space.
The grid is the base for a cylinder and an ico sphere which shall be morphed into each other.

The individual objects are then realized on their position.

Now their position is split into 2 parameters: the x value and the y value. Then the object is taken out of the grid and based on their x and y value the get morphed into the other object.

So for example if an object is at the position 0, 0 on the grid its a cylinder and if it would be at the position 1,1 it would be a sphere. Now the matrix morphes the objects together based on their position in space.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Could you elaborate a bit about how this works? Add a short written description about your solution so it can be indexed and searched for in the future

Comment: Hello, i've edited my answer but since i am not a native speaker i dont know if my explenation was any good. Would be nice if you could give me any feedback.